# Adding If / If Not statement into PowerShell

Tags: powershell

We are moving to JumpCloud AD services, and with that, comes automated deployment commands from the JumpCloud console. I've created a script that works with Chocolatey to install some apps, and the ones not on Chocolatey I have them in an S3 bucket on AWS that I've tied into a `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri` command to pull the package, and copy it to the destination folder.

The problem I'm running into, is, I want the command to run, but I want it to check and see if the install files are already there, if they are, move onto the next item, if they aren't, then copy the file over.

Anyone willing to give me a few pointers? Currently have 7 packages being copied over, so I assume I'll need 7 `if` statements.

Here is the code of what I have attempted so far:

```
if ( -not (Test-Path -path "C:\Windows\Temp\JC_ScheduledTasks")) {
     New-Item -Path "C:\Windows\Temp\JC_ScheduledTasks" -ItemType directory
}
```

But I'm not sure how to tweak that for items pulled from AWS:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "cavo-deploy-virginia.s3.amazonaws.com/QualysCloudAgent.exe" -OutFile "c:\jumpcloud\QualysCloudAgent.exe"
```

Comment: If you are looking to see if a file exists you want to use `Test-Path`

Comment: So, I have this:

if ( -not (Test-Path -path "C:\Windows\Temp\JC_ScheduledTasks"))
{
    New-Item -Path "C:\Windows\Temp\JC_ScheduledTasks" -ItemType directory
}

But I'm not sure how to tweak that for items pulled from AWS:

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://cavo-deploy-virginia.s3.amazonaws.com/QualysCloudAgent.exe" -OutFile "c:\jumpcloud\QualysCloudAgent.exe"

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to format that for code... kinda new to this :S

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you have tried and what is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have an array of files that you want to do the same set of commands for. Then use simple loop either using `foreach` or `ForEach-Object`.

```
$DestinationFolder = 'c:\jumpcloud\'                                                       #'

# Define the array here or use Get-Content for a list from a text file
$Files = @('QualysCloudAgent.exe','example1.exe')

foreach ($File in $Files) {

    # Determine the destination for the file
    $DestinationFile = Join-Path $DestinationFolder $File

    # Validate if the file already exists
    if ( -not (Test-Path $DestinationFile)) {
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "cavo-deploy-virginia.s3.amazonaws.com/$File" -OutFile $DestinationFile
    }
}
```

Comment: So with this example, the validation path above the IF statement - what would I put for it to move the file if it doesn't exist? I don't see anything in there that says if the file exists to move on, if not copy file over. Sorry if these are stupid questions, I'm just starting out learning, so any help is appreciated

Comment: I was able to tweak this and get it working! Thank you so much!